# MVC routing, culture settings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I make these two types of links act the same? (in ASP.NET MVC)

```
example.com/en/action/controller
example.com/action/controller
```

I have a site with several languages: en, nl, de, etc. When I request links with specified language - all works fine. But when I manually remove "/en/", "/de/" etc. - I get a "not found" error.

I need to fix it. So when a user requests URL without typing "/en/" or "/de/" - he will get a page with default language (in my case - english).

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want different routing.

However I would like you to see this link from a Legend SCOTT HANSELMAN

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

Its having everything of what you want and I am sure you can rethink about your approach.